# angularjs - post specific elements of an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm using nodejs, mongodb, angular and html to make a RESTful service. I'm new at this and I have some problems!

With the next code of the controller,  I'm sending the variable "fp" to my database:

```
$http.post('/fplist', $scope.fp);
```

It works pretty well but "fp" value is:

```
fpdia: Wed Nov 01 2017
fphora: 00:00:00
fppilot:{_id: "59f06a0f907c783d6ccb8901", nombre: "Mike Ross", iden: "111222333A", rpasenable: "Phantom1", $$hashKey: "object:10"}
fprpas:{_id: "59f1b8bbdbae0a23208d0ad8", model: "Phantom1", serial: "4444-444-4444", plate: "123 TT", $$hashKey: "object:14"}
fptitulo:"Test"
```

And I just want to save "fp" like:

```
fpdia: Wed Nov 01 2017
fphora: 00:00:00
fppilot: Mike Ross
fprpas: 123 TT
fptitulo:"Test"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create another json object:

So, before you do your http request you just have to do this:

```
var obj = {
    fpdia: $scope.fp.fpdia,
    fphora: $scope.fp.fphora,
    fppilot: $scope.fp.fppilot.nombre,
    fprpas: $scope.fp.fprpas.plate,
    fptitulo: $scope.fp.fptitulo
}

$http.post('/fplist', obj);
```